# How do pass template class pointer to the same class

Tags: c++, templates

I know the problem in the following code, but not sure about the solution.

As the templatized parameter is MOD, in the function 'func' it is expecting MOD to be of same type for both the calle class and the class pointer passed as parameter.

```
template <class MOD>
class Test {
    public:
        void func(Test<MOD>* _ptr);
        Test(MOD* _m, int _val);
        int ival;
    private:
        MOD* _mod;
};

template <class MOD>
Test<MOD>::Test(MOD* _m, int _val) {
   _mod = _m;
    ival = _val;
}

template <class MOD> 
void Test<MOD>::func(Test<MOD>* _ptr) {
    if(ival == _ptr->ival)
        std::cout << "Equal values " << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Unequal values " << std::endl;
}

class T1 {
    public:
        Test<T1>* _test1;
        T1() : _test1(NULL) {
            _test1 = new Test<T1>(this, 4); 
        }   
        ~T1() {
            delete _test1; _test1 = NULL;
        }
};

class T2 {
    public:
public:
        Test<T2>* _test2;
        T2() : _test2 (NULL) {
            _test2 = new Test<T2>(this, 5);
        }
        ~T2() {
            delete _test2; _test2 = NULL;
        }
};

int main() {
    T1 t1;
    T2 t2;
    t1._test1->func(t2._test2);
    return 0;
}
```

How can i solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this

```
template <class MOD>
class Test {
    public:
        template<class T> void func(Test<T>* _ptr);

        Test(MOD* _m, int _val);
        int ival;
    private:
        MOD* _mod;
};


template <class MOD> 
template <class T>
void Test<MOD>::func(Test<T>* _ptr) {
    if(ival == _ptr->ival)
        std::cout << "Equal values " << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Unequal values " << std::endl;
}
```

`func` should be a template method inside a template class.